# Missing Jetty SVN trunk directory

Tags: eclipse, svn, maven, jetty

[m2e in minutes](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) video references the [Jetty SVN trunk](http://svn.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty/trunk) directory which does not exist. What is the correct value to use at this time?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Jetty is now under Git source control, but the legacy SVN repo is still available:

- [Jetty SVN repo](http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.jetty/)
- [Jetty Git repo](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git)

[Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/downloads.php), [logs](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/VERSION.txt), and [archives](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/releases) are also linked from the [doc site](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/).